# C# auto update variable in dictionary is possible?

Tags: c#

Example I Using This Code but this code not changing value in the dictionary auto update value in dictionary on changed is possible ?

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private void DoWork()
{
        dic.Add("data", "example1");
        dic.Add("data2", "example2");
        if(dic.TryGetValue("data",out string c))
        {
            c = "Value Changed Good";
        }

        foreach (string s in dic.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
}
```

Example this code output is a

```
example1
example2
```

but value not changed example if value changed this output changed with this

```
Value Changed Good
example2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the value stored in Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243717/how-to-update-the-value-stored-in-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: `if (dic.ContainsKey("data")) dic["data"] = "Value Changed Good";`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, that would be suboptimal, since it will require 2 look up, right?

Comment: @Sinatr: in case of ordinary `Dictionary<K, V>` we don't have `UpdateIfExist` or alike and have to perform 2 looking up (it's not that expensive if we have a good hash). In case of `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>` we can do the modification in one go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update collection items, you should probably use the solution provided in [Oliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67087471/4174789). That's the most straightforward way to go, I guess.

If you want to avoid a duplicate lookup when updating collection values in your `for`-loop, you could consider wrapping your collection values in a wrapper object. It could look something like this:

```cs
class Wrapper
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, Wrapper> dic = new Dictionary<string, Wrapper>();

private void DoWork()
{
    dic.Add("data", new Wrapper { Value = "example1" });
    dic.Add("data2", new Wrapper { Value = "example2" });

    if (dic.TryGetValue("data", out Wrapper c))
    {
        c.Value = "Value Changed Good";
    }

    foreach (Wrapper s in dic.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Value);
    }
}
```

But mind that this will also introduce additional overhead (especially when reading values from the dictionary). And it will probably make your code somewhat harder to read and understand as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the value of your local variable `c`, this doesn't affect the value within the dictionary.

To update the value within the Dictionary you can do something like this:

```
var key = "data";
if(dic.TryGetValue(key,out string c))
{
    c = "Value Changed Good";
    dic[key] = c;
}
```

Comment: Is this answer accurate for normal reference types? (yes, I know string is an exception) Edit: Accurate meaning, "this doesn't affect the value within the dictionary". I believe reference types are mutable.

Comment: @JohnD This is accurate for all reference types. If you assign a new value to `c`, this means `c` points to a new address in memory. The variable stored in the dictionary will still point to the old address in memory.

Comment: Ty, I didn't account for the out param being a new local var.