# Add extra character to value if key is present in the dictionary using linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to add "_new" to the existing value if a key is present in the Dictionary object else want to keep it blank.

I have a dictionary object

```
"LanguageMapping": {
    "LanguageMappingCode": {
      "en-CA": "ca-en",
      "fr-CA": "ca-fe",
      "ab-GB": "gb-ab",  
.....so on    
    }
  }
```

I am using Linq to fetch the value from key.

```
_languageMapping.LanguageMappingCode.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == LanguageCode)Value
```

Currently, I am getting a response as "ca-en" if I pass key "en-CA" but I want a response as "ca-en_new".

Is it possible to achieve using Linq?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the value stored in Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243717/how-to-update-the-value-stored-in-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: I want to achieve something like dict[key] = value + newValue but using Linq and at run time

Comment: Not easily, without creating a new dictionary (which seems an expensive operation).  Does the value in the dictionary need to change, or the value you use?  If the latter, just append `_new` to the `Value` you get from the dictionary

Comment: @Martin here can we do something with Value of Linq without using + or append? _languageMapping.LanguageMappingCode.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == LanguageCode)Value

Comment: There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31073047/1997232) in duplicate.

Comment: @user2148124 You will ultimately have to use `+ "_new"` or append even if you do it in pure Linq.  How else would you make the new string?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on whether you just want to modify the value you use from the `Dictionary`, or whether you want to update all of the values in the `Dictionary` (or something else).

This will create a new `Dictionary` that has `_new` appended to every value:

```
var newDict = _languageMapping.LanguageMappingCode.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value + "_new");
```

This is an expensive operation.

Otherwise you can just append `_new` to the value before you use it:

```
var value = _languageMapping.LanguageMappingCode.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == LanguageCode).Value + "_new";
```

Comment: I want to form a new value without using + or append.

Comment: @user2148124 Why?  I can't think of any simple way to concatenate two strings without using `+` or `string.Append`.